# How to host a web server for the offline documentation temporarily?

Tags: server, documentation

Many programming languages and SDK (like Android Studio, Java, ...) provide their documentation for offline in the form of web pages. But when serving those files from the disk, Chrome is not able to fetch file types other than web page like JSON, ... and @import query does not works...

I don't want to use server like XAMPP for this. Because I am already using that for development purposes. Help me with a way to host a temporary light-weight server with web_root as the documentation folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the node package "http-server".

You must have node.js (v4.4.0 or greater) installed and from the command line/terminal the http-server package can be installed by using this command:
`npm install -g http-server`

Navigate to the local directory containing the files you want to serve and call `http-server` from the command line/terminal.

Your pages will be hosted by default on

> http://localhost:8080

Do not close the command line/terminal as this will stop the serving.

Comment: It worked! But how would I change the port on which it would be hosted

Comment: When you are using "http-server" just add "-p" and give the port you wish to use instead of the default. More information on the different arguments to be used can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server